# gulp serve - where to add socket.io and controller

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp

I have a gulp-angular-generator based app. At the moment , I have something like this in the server.js :

```css
browserSync.instance = browserSync.init({
    startPath: '/',
    server: server,
    browser: browser
  });
}

browserSync.use(browserSyncSpa({
  selector: '[ng-app]'// Only needed for angular apps
}));

gulp.task('serve', ['watch'], function () {
  browserSyncInit([path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve'), conf.paths.src]);
});

gulp.task('serve:dist', ['build'], function () {
  browserSyncInit(conf.paths.dist);
});

gulp.task('serve:e2e', ['inject'], function () {
  browserSyncInit([conf.paths.tmp + '/serve', conf.paths.src], []);
});

gulp.task('serve:e2e-dist', ['build'], function () {
  browserSyncInit(conf.paths.dist, []);
});
```

I am strugling to understand how can I add either express and or socket.io into this code .

I would like to add "server side" code into the gulp environment. 
Thanks,
Gabor